# How can a reasonable faith be placed in the Being that inspired the Bible if it is "inspired" but not "inerrant"?

Tags: bible, inspiration, inerrancy

This question (and two related sub-questions) is directed towards **those who believe that the Bible is inspired but not inerrant**.  I understand inerrant to simply mean "without error".  "Inspired" tends to have more nuances in it's meaning and so a valid answer should include a short definitional statement describing "inspired" as well as one regarding "inerrant" if it is taken differently.

If the Bible is not inerrant, i.e. if it contains errors, and yet is inspired by God does this not mean that the errors are inspired?

1. How and why would God inspire error without being deceptive or fallible?
2. Without an inspired and inerrant listing of Biblical error, how can one reliably discern Biblical error and should one make the effort if the error is inspired?

Comment: Note that **answers must present the errantist perspective**, which means the Bible had **errors in the original manuscripts**. Purely transmission or translation errors do not count, as they are already accounted for by inerrantists. For example, [one errantist said](https://t.ly/2d8oP) "Anything that involves humans comes with a taint: and that includes products resulting from God’s use of human agents to reveal himself. Humans often hijack and distort God’s message. That’s how God in the Bible is made to promote genocide, regulate slavery, and ban women from church leadership."

Comment: **Clarification**  Questions here should be  clarified. Because God "inspires" a man, He does not "inspire" the errors a man makes! Just as when God anoints a man for ministry who subsequently commits a sin, does not mean that God anointed the sin! .....Be careful that infallible deity be not attributed to any man, inspired or not. The only inspired Person who knew no sin was Jesus, and Him alone. The arguing among the N.T. ministers proves that ordination does not imply inerrant behavior. God uses imperfect men, though, sufficiently to present the Gospel, which an infant can understand.

Answer (score 9):

I think this can be addressed in a similar way to how theists respond to the [Problem of Evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_evil) objection against the existence of God: how can a perfectly loving, omnipotent and omniscient God allow evil to exist in His creation? One common response is that God has allowed evil to exist because He probably has good reasons for doing so. So, if God has good reasons for allowing evil to exist in His perfectly designed Creation, why wouldn't God also have good reasons for allowing errors to exist in His perfectly inspired Sacred Scriptures?

Now, responding to your specific requests and questions:

> so a valid answer should include a short definitional statement describing "inspired" as well as one regarding "inerrant" if it is taken differently.

- **Inspired**: God intervenes in the universe by prompting one or more human beings to record statements for future generations to read. The prompting might or might not explicitly enforce the recording of very specific statements word by word, and similarly, the prompting might or might not allow some noise or errors to be introduced in the process.
- **Inerrant**: The entirety of Scripture contains 0% errors of any kind.

> If the Bible is not inerrant, i.e. if it contains errors, and yet is inspired by God does this not mean that the errors are inspired?

Not necessarily, the errors might ultimately be traced back to a different cause. For example, if you believe in free will, it's possible that the errors are contingent upon mistakes freely made by human beings, thus interrupting the causal chain towards God. Why would God allow this? Perhaps for the same reasons that He has allowed evil to exist.

> How and why would God inspire error without being deceptive or fallible?

This question presupposes that God inspired the error, which is not necessarily the case (see my answer above to your previous question). However, if we replace *inspire* with *allow*, the answer would be: in the same way and for the same reasons that God allows evil to exist in the world without that being an excuse for atheists to claim that God is "deceiving" them by supposedly "making them believe" that He doesn't exist. Christians assert that the Creation points toward the Creator (the teleological argument). Atheists claim that all the evil and suffering in the world points toward the inexistence of a loving Creator (the argument from evil). If God can allow evil and suffering without being deceptive (thus invalidating the atheist's complaints), why can't God allow error without being deceptive (thus invalidating the inerrantist's complaints)?

> Without an inspired and inerrant listing of Biblical error, how can one reliably discern Biblical error and should one make the effort if the error is inspired?

Ignoring the fact that this question presupposes yet again a questionable *"if the error is inspired"* (see answers to specific questions above), I presume the most reliable method would be for God Himself to assist the believer in doing the discerning, or to directly guide the believer towards the right interpretation.

**Note**: Entertaining the idea of God inspiring errors is analogous to entertaining the idea of God causing people to sin. God doesn't force people to sin, and yet people might still sin. In a similar manner, God doesn't inspire errors, and yet errors might still occur. But it is true that God is overseeing the whole process in both cases, and only allowing them to happen within certain boundaries such that His purposes are still fulfilled.

Comment: This is an insightful application of the problem of evil. +1

Comment: If errors are included within Scripture by causes outside of the inspiration of God, i.e. human free will choices/mistakes, how can they be held as inspired, at least inspired as a whole?  But this question is not about a Scripture that is considered partly inspired.  I think this answer actually negates inspiration in the same way that evil being (correctly) understood as allowed by God for His sovereign purposes results in the understanding that evil is not caused or inspired by God.  We never see Jesus correcting the Scriptures themselves, just human interpretation.

Comment: @MikeBorden Any errors can be traced back to a cause other than God. So yes, you could say that a given set of manuscripts can be considered *partly* inspired if an erroneous fraction was not inspired.  I don't see anything wrong with that. `We never see Jesus correcting the Scriptures themselves, just human interpretation` This is an argument from silence. Besides, the New Testament was not around yet at the time.

Answer (score 5):

The answer for me depends on how one thinks of God's omnipotence. If God is absolutely all-powerful then inspiration = inerrancy. However, if God limits his power to allow for human freedom, then inspiration allows for human error. In other words, God inspires the author of the text but does not verbally dictate it, nor does he directly control the transmission of the text or the attribution of biblical writings to specific authors.

This hypothesis allows for differences of theological perspective as well as factual anomalies and misattributions. Thus, for example, the Book of Job can tell us that God allows the terrible suffering of a man whom He has certified to be "blameless" (Job 1:8) while Proverbs 28:18 assures us that "Whoever walks blamelessly is safe." Copyist errors and insertions may also be included in the canon, and books traditionally attributed to an author such as Mark or Matthew may not have actually been written by them.

The question of pseudepigrapha is more difficult. Would God inspire the creation of biblical books supposedly written by specific authors who did not actually write them? For example many believe that David did not write some of the psalms attributed to him, or that Paul is not the author of the Pastoral Epistles, or that Moses did not actually write the Torah. To those who believe this but also affirm that the Bible is "God-breathed" the answer would be that God works in strange and mysterious ways. (Romans 11:33)

Short answers to the secondary questions.

- "How and why would God inspire error without being deceptive or fallible?" Answer: God does not inspire error; he inspires authors who are vulnerable to mistakes and cultural prejudices.
- "How can one reliably discern Biblical error and should one make the effort if the error is inspired?" I don't say that errors are inspired. But in any case one has to pray for discernment and approach the scripture diligently guided by one's conscience.

Comment: The answer is that the Bible is inspired but also contains uninspired errors?  Wouldn't that mean that the Bible is only partly inspired or do you hold the original autographs (not extant) as fully inspired?

Comment: Safe in what sense? I do not see how this necessitates a textual anomaly, given how vague a term such as "safe" can be. Safe from what? I believe verses such as 2 Timothy 3:12 help to clarify that this is not a guarantee against misfortune.
One problem I have with pseudepigraphic theories is that they vary, and a mistaken theory does not imply a textual error. The attribution had to come from somewhere, and sometimes is not made entirely clear in the text. A paraphrasing or retelling of an account could also convey evidences of pseudepigrapha even though the original authorship is authentic.

Comment: @MikeBorden... Original autographs would not solve the problem for me. II prefer "generally inspired" to  "partly inspired" but I do think that some biblical authors were imperfect channels.

Comment: @pygosceles... I prefer not  to deal with the question of "safe from what" here. My point is that I accept that the bible's authors do not share the same opinion on various issues. For me  they all fall under that umbrella of what I'd call general inspiration.

Comment: @DanFefferman In the KJV the same Proverb is read "Whoso walketh uprightly shall be saved", and it is not the common reading in Christian culture to say that this implies that a person will be spared temporal disasters, disease or discomfort. The ancient prophets who were imprisoned, beheaded, stoned, sawn asunder, and so on are saved, yet they were afflicted at many points in like manner as Job was.
So I am saying I don't think this makes a strong case for any disagreement between Biblical authors.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the nature of Christ, there are few matters as divisive among Christians as the doctrine of Inspiration of the Bible.  There are two questions that arise from the doctrine of inspiration: (1) How does divine inspiration work? And, (2) What is inspired?

**How Does Inspiration Work?**

Traditionally, there have been three broad views about how the Bible writers were inspired:

1. Verbal Inspiration: The Holy Spirit dictated the Bible, word for word.
2. Thought Inspiration:  The Holy Spirit inspired men’s ideas; prophets then expressed these ideas in their own words.
3. The Bible contains the Word of God, that is, it records the experiences of great and Godly men and so has other material not necessarily inspired.  That is, in the judgement of those who subscribe to this view, some parts of the Bible are not worthy of the sacred canon.  This might be called “non-plenary”, “incomplete”, or “partial” inspiration.

We will ignore the third view as an example of “Cafeteria Theology” where one is free to decide what parts of the Bible to believe and what can be ignored.  Let us assume immediately that the entire Bible, as we have it, is inspired, as declared in 2 Tim 3:16, 17, 2 Peter 1:19-21.  See also 2 Sam 23:2, Neh 9:30, Eze 2:2, 11:5, 24, Micah 3:8, Zech 7:12, 2 Peter 1:19-21, Rom 1:2, 3:2, Heb 3:7, 5:12, 9:8, Mark 12:36, Acts 28:25, 1 Tim 4:1.

- Paul says that “the spirits of the prophets are subject to the prophets” (1 Cor 14:32) indicating that the prophet does not lose his/her personality in the process.

Lastly, if God had dictated the words of the Bible intending that they would be immutable and important, then God would have miraculously preserved the exact words as inspired and “dictated”.  Even a casual glace at the history of the Bible text suggests that this was never the case – there are thousands of variations in the Bible text, but all preserve the ideas in the text.  That is, while many “errors” and variations exist in the Bible text between manuscripts, none are significant for the message.

Thus, the Bible, God’s Word and its central message of God’s love and salvation, has been miraculously preserved but not necessarily the exact words that the Bible writers used.  (It is possible that some Bible writers produced more than one version or revision themselves!?)

**What is Inspired?**

The question of what is inspired can be asked other ways:

- Might there be other books that have been omitted that should be either included in the canon of Scripture or at least considered inspired?
- Was the gift of prophecy closed with the canon of Scripture or could further prophets arise that, while not adding to Scripture, could still have relevant messages after the 1st century?

The second question is simpler than the first.  There is nothing in the Bible suggesting that the gift of prophecy was to finish with John the Revelator.  Quite the contrary; the list of spiritual gifts in the New Testament always includes the gift of prophecy.

There are numerous (some valid and some false) prophets who wrote or spoke material not included in the Bible.  The NT's Agabus is a perfect example of a valid prophet whose various prophesies were not included in the Bible.  The four daughters of Philip are another example.

This still leaves the question about what material was included in the Bible and why. Generally, material was included that was written by someone who had first-hand knowledge of what they were writing either by divine revelation or as a witness to the events as described.  All forgeries were excluded by the early church fathers.  When examining the many documents omitted from the New Testament, it becomes quite obvious why they were excluded.

Answer (score 1):

This question begs the question of **what the Bible is**.
Did "the Bible" as such exist at the time any of its constituent texts were written? No, not by a hundred years or more. There is not a single unanimously recognized version of it either. There are many versions and translations. It is apparent that Adam, Enoch, Noah and Abraham all kept records which Moses used as source materials to consolidate his account regarding the Creation, the Flood etc. which constitutes most of Genesis, but we do not have the original accounts, although they would be Scripture if we had them. This does not need to destroy our confidence, however. Is "the Bible" a collection of *mostly-inspired* abridgements, prophetic accounts and apostolic texts?
**Yes.**

What is the degree of faithful preservation and translation of the original texts? This would be impossible to tell without revelation from God. Even if someone comes forward with a purported original manuscript of a Biblical text, it will be impossible to confirm its authenticity through purely secular means.

Inspired, assuming we are talking about the Holy Spirit, means that the Spirit of God was the driving force behind the creation of the text. On the whole the Bible is mostly inspired.

Ice cream can be delicious, good and pure and then have some toxic elements added to it. This does not mean that the ice cream itself is bad or that its origin is evil. The devil likes to do this to all good things to throw us off the scent of eternal life.
Yes, the devil has tampered with the Bible, and translators' ignorant minds and hands have smudged its pages some. Evidences of this are abundant, for example, numerous passages saying that "it repented God..."/"God repented" (Genesis 6:6) while from other passages we know that God cannot repent because He does not sin (Numbers 23:19).

When we say "The Bible is inspired" we do not necessarily mean that everything put into some current compilation is of God, or that every translation or rendering of it is correct and accurate. Some translations are more accurate and honest than others. For one example, In Acts 7:48, the word "dwell" used in the KJV (Greek 2730) means "to house permanently, reside". In Revelation 7:15, the word "dwell" in the KJV as "dwell" more accurately means "to tent or encamp" (Greek 4637), showing divergent connotations becoming flattened and lost in translation. Without a more robust translation, this important distinction is lost, leading to potentially catastrophic misunderstandings, for example assuming that the word of God is self-contradictory when in fact the error is due to a lack of distinction from a translator. Such errors might also lead us erroneously to discard portions of God's true words. Therefore the existence of apparent contradictions by itself does not always allow us to determine whether it is a translation error or a deliberate pejoration of the text, without introducing additional errors of our own.

> How and why would God inspire error without being deceptive or fallible?

God does not inspire error. It's that simple. If there are errors they are the mistakes or deliberate alterations of men. We can use a scalpel or a spoon to extricate mistakes and messes that have been dumped in and make corrections -- but only if we are inspired.

> Without an inspired and inerrant listing of Biblical error, how can one reliably discern Biblical error and should one make the effort if the error is inspired?

Fortunately God knew we would have this problem and prepared a solution for it:
He called a modern seer to provide an inspired revision and retranslation of the Bible, which corrects some of the most significant errors and redactions that have accumulated in the texts underlying the Bible.
You can read it here and compare to the redacted and altered versions to see how it enhances your understanding of God's dealings with mankind from the beginning. It is even called the "Inspired Version" of the Bible:

[Joseph Smith's Inspired Translation of the Bible](https://archive.org/details/holyscriptures00smit/page/n17/mode/2up)

Comment: Thomas Jefferson also rewrote the Bible, removing everything miraculous and saying "This is a Jesus I can believe in".  This "modern seer' you refer to says that "as man is God once was and as God is man may become".  This is a contradiction of the entirety of the Biblical message, not the correction of a little mistake here or there.  It is an entirely different religion.

Comment: @MikeBorden All the prophets and apostles anciently testified that we are the children of God, not robots or playthings. Mankind alone has this distinction.
If you want to know where the "What is a woman?" confusion came from, look no further than the post-apostasy pseudochristians who equivocate obvious answers to the questions "What is a father?" "What is a child?" into make-believe absurdities.
What child do you know of that is incapable of becoming like his parents?
The Divine potential of man through Jesus Christ is the religion of those who believe the Bible. The contrary is idolatry.

Comment: Adam was a created son, made of the dust of the earth and with life breathed in.  Not like the other creatures and yet a creature ... a servant.  God is not so.  He was not made of dust nor brought into existence.   He is the Creator with no beginning.  He has no equal and never will.  The culmination of the age comes and those in Christ are still servants not Gods:  "And there shall be no more curse: but the throne of God and of the Lamb shall be in it; and his servants shall serve him:  And they shall see his face; and his name shall be in their foreheads." - Rev. 22:3-4

Comment: "How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations! For thou hast said in thine heart, I will ascend into heaven, I will exalt my throne above the stars of God: I will sit also upon the mount of the congregation, in the sides of the north: I will ascend above the heights of the clouds; I will be like the most High.  Yet thou shalt be brought down to hell, to the sides of the pit." - Isaiah 14:12-15

Comment: @MikeBorden
"The Spirit itself beareth witness with our spirit, that we are the children of God:
And if children, then heirs; heirs of God, and joint-heirs with Christ; if so be that we suffer with him, that we may be also glorified together." Romans 8:16-17
You don't have to believe it but if you do not you will limit your relationship with God.
Lucifer sought to ascend by pride rather than obedience. By suffering jointly with Christ we will receive all that the Father has, just as He has become even as the Father is.

Comment: Well, we are at an impasse for sure.  It is the Spirit of adoption by which I cry, Abba.   I fully expect, as Revelation 22 indicates, to worship and serve God forever (this is why man was created) and I will refuse to my last dying breath the temptation to expect that I will become God.  Beside Him there is no other:  One God only, ever.   I am not God and will never, ever be.  My relationship with the one true God is thus secure, in Christ.

Comment: @MikeBorden In no family tree does a son replace his father. His father remains forever, as does the son, and every son can become a father. Our Father in Heaven has shown us deliberately His plan for us through His Beloved Son.

Comment: "And I heard a great voice out of heaven saying, Behold, the tabernacle of God is with men, and he will dwell with them, and they shall be his people, and God himself shall be with them, and be their God."  God's people shall forever have Him as their God.  Nowhere are we told that we ourselves shall become Gods, creating and ruling our own universes:  That is a man-made addition to what is written.  Please consider Revelation 22:18.

Comment: @MikeBorden And each man's father will forever be his father if they both submit to God's design. There is nothing remotely controversial or new about this. It is the simple meaning of words as they have always been ordained and revealed by God. The notion of the dissolution of families is to put asunder what God has joined together.
There is absolutely nothing in Scripture that precludes the continuation of families including in the realm of God, except through disobedience. In fact an impotent god is a boring god, and a familyless god is no god at all. God is our Father, this is true.

Comment: Always having God as Father and becoming Gods ourselves are wildly different.  Supposing that Almighty God was once something less than He is unthinkable, unbiblical ... such a being is no God at all.  If you allow for multiple Gods, your Gods are too small.  "I am the LORD, I have no peer, there is no God but me."  Amen.

Comment: @MikeBorden God is a deliberate Teacher. Nothing of His creation is intended for nothingness or waste, but all is meant for fruition. Consider the first commandment after God gave Adam and Eve to each other in marriage: to multiply and fill the Earth. There is no such thing in all Creation as a child that is incapable of becoming like his parents, and we are the children of God. The Apostles even say so. Of course to a credal view this sounds like blasphemy. But that is only because the creeds are entirely distinct from the teachings of the Bible. A god who is impotent is no god at all.

Comment: Your aspiration is to become equal to God and the God that you hope to be equal to is one that used to be like like us:  That God does not exist.  God is, from everlasting to everlasting, unchanging.  He did not become what He is.  Not based upon creeds but upon what has been written.  I would wish you luck in your endeavor but I do not wish you luck.  I wish you ears to hear and Merry Christmas.

Comment: @MikeBorden You ascribe it to filthy aspiration but it comes by invitation from God.
Again, a god who created everything in the universe merely for show is not a very powerful god. It harks back to the geocentrist model, which was a dogma of an apostate religion, and has been proven utterly false.
The entire message of the Bible is "God with us" (Matthew 1:23), not "God is a stranger from us". The Lord taught that those who do not know Him are those who do not serve Him, and many will say "Lord, Lord", but He will not open to them, because they knew Him not.

Comment: @MikeBorden The creeds say He is a stranger, a blob, a "thing" to be revered from afar but not embraced. He is not a stranger. He is our Father. This is what the Scriptures say. We can and must approach Him as a child does to his Father.
Merry Christmas is to return to the presence of God and be like Him; 1 John 3:2. I look forward to that day. If I am not like Him, then my faith is vain. The ascension of the Son of God into heaven to possess all that His Father has and the promise that we may be joint heirs with Him would be null and void, making every prophet of Scripture a liar.

Comment: @MikeBorden "Seeing then that we have a great high priest, that is passed into the heavens, Jesus the Son of God, let us hold fast our profession. For we have not an high priest which cannot be touched with the feeling of our infirmities; but was in all points tempted like as we are, yet without sin. Let us therefore come boldly unto the throne of grace, that we may obtain mercy, and find grace to help in time of need" Hebrews 4:14-16. Therefore I hold fast my testimony, which is the true testimony of Scripture, that man is literally a child of God and can indeed become joint-heir with Christ.

Comment: Joint heirs with Christ, indeed.  When we see Him (Jesus) we shall be like Him, indeed.  Exactly like Him in every way?  Certainly not, for those in Him have been redeemed and He needed no redemption.  He was God in the beginning and we were not.  He, sinless ... we forgiven.  A created son (Adam) ... a begotten son (Christ)... the adoption of sons for those in Christ.  Adam swallowed the temptation to be like God and ruined us all.  The Gospel is not of flesh becoming God but God becoming flesh to reconcile everything to Himself.  The ungodly are justified ... not deified.

Comment: @MikeBorden the Savior told us what exactly He would inherit from His Father: "All things that the Father hath". The exact same things He offers to us through the virtue of His great atoning sacrifice.
You can believe it, or not, but that is what He said. The creeds throw up limits on God. They choose to believe only part of Scripture instead of all of it. But God is greater than those manmade limitations. The very meaning of the word "reconcile" proves that man was in the beginning with God.
There is more than justification. There is also sanctification. There is also perfection.

Comment: @MikeBorden The Savior also repeatedly commanded us throughout Scripture, "Be ye therefore perfect, even as your Father … in heaven is perfect."
By very nature, it is impossible to become perfect, even as our Father in Heaven, without receiving the fullness of His attributes. He repeatedly declared that with man this was impossible, but through Him, all things are possible--even becoming one with Himself and His Father, and becoming as the Father is.

Comment: @MikeBorden This is throughout Scripture and it is the Savior's ultimate invitation to us.
The doctrine that we are not really children of God but mere puppets or automata or cannot become like Him is a purely unscriptural creed, and is a manmade invention, or is the very calculation of the adversary to get those who will be blinded to have no interest in living the fullness of God's plan.

Comment: @MikeBorden Much of this confusion begins with one of the first words in the Creation account, the Hebrew word ba-ra, which means "to call forth; cause to assemble", but the ancient credalists invented a new meaning that never existed in any language, and say that in this lone instance means causing things to poof from nothing. That is not what the word means at all. There is no word for it because there is no such act.
The song in the Sound of Music sets it straight: "Nothing comes from nothing -- Nothing ever could".
Ex nihilo is false. Man is literally a spirit child of God.

Comment: If what you say were true Adam would have been rewarded for trying to be like God in knowing good from evil.  "For God knows that when you eat of it your eyes will be opened, and you will be like God, knowing good and evil.".  It is not the limitation of any creed but the heart of satanic deception which tells a man that he can become God.  It is the way of death.  Regarding *bara*:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/77492/32868

Comment: @MikeBorden No. God rewards His children for obedience to His commandments, which necessarily makes us more like God, Who has perfect self-mastery.
Satan told Adam and Eve a half-truth; it is true that God knows good and evil but it is not true that God is disobedient to eternal law.
Saying that we cannot become like God (the literal promise of the Savior that we can become joint-heirs with Him through His Atonement, and He is heir to all that His Father has), is falling for the devil's reverse psychology and rejecting a true claim. Remember not everything the devil says is false.

Comment: @MikeBorden With regards to bara, there is no such thing as a word in any language to my knowledge that means "to exnihilate". I had to invent such a word on the spot to express the concept. To shape, form or fashion necessitates the pre-existence of material. I love you and I know this is true. The Spirit of God attests it is true to every soul that has desires to follow Him and sincerely inquires of Him. This will shape the eternal destiny of every soul who applies.

Comment: Christ, the only begotten Son, has inherited all things.  We are children and co-heirs by the spirit of adoption.  We are invited into His inheritance which is God's creation.  The word *kleros* is often translated with "heir" of an "inheritance" but where in English the act of inheriting is commonly associated with the passing away of a relative, this Greek word clearly also describes the sharing of the revenues of an existing enterprise without the transfer of ownership.  God and Jesus never cease being over us in creation and we never become their equals or replacements.

Comment: I, too, know this is true for this Lord Jesus has saved me and is saving me.  It is no theological construct but an actuality that occurred in keeping with what the Bible says.  Unfortunately we cannot both be correct and I am so sure that I am begging you to receive the One who is forever the Lord of Glory.  The God I worship and serve was not once a being formed from dust.

Comment: @MikeBorden "We are invited into His inheritance which is" ALL that the Father has.
This is what the Son says. We could not come boldly to the throne of grace if we did not believe God's words about His desire to make us His full heirs together with Christ.
In the case of God, we are indeed entitled through faith and grace to become heirs and co-participants in the Father's family business, namely, the creation, population, redemption and exaltation of His children in worlds without number. Hence it is a Living Inheritance. I have written about this before. Of course we never replace Them.

Comment: @MikeBorden But again, all of this is not only consistent, it is congruent with the meaning of being a child of God. You yourself just said that the text says that God continues to create--which thing we can easily observe. Since He continues to create, He also continues to populate, redeem and exalt His children in worlds without number. We could not meaningfully participate in this greatest family enterprise if we did not gain mastery over creation ourselves, or have the potential for progeny.
This is what the Son does. It is what we can do if we are worthy.

Comment: @MikeBorden My God has overcome all things, and so knows how and is perfectly empowered to help His children to overcome all things. My God is greater than an empty-headed fatalistic phenomenon. He arrived at His station by virtue. What is the great story of redemption? That man may be redeemed and progress and become a full heir with God in every sense. The Scriptures say so. I do not persecute you or anyone in your belief, you are entitled to it. But no one can deny that a God who has overcome is greater than a god who simply always enjoyed fullness of glory without having to do anything.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree with " no one can deny that a God who has overcome is greater than a god who simply always enjoyed fullness of glory without having to do anything.".  A God that had to overcome in order to be God is a God who could have failed.  I do not worship such a God.

Comment: @MikeBorden A God who could have failed but chose not to is infinitely greater than a god who was never tested.
God is not God because He won the Calvinist lottery. He is God because He placed perfect trust in the infinite plan of eternal progress and growth. He is God because He built the character sufficient to sacrifice His own comfort, His live and His Beloved Son for the benefit of His posterity. That God who is our bona fide Father is infinitely more powerful, benevolent and wise than the false god of random tosses of dice for power and position. We as His children must be tested.

Comment: Making assertions that directly contradict the Bible (Isaiah 45:5) does not help your position.  Additionally, the God of a theology which allows for multiple Gods is too small to be God.  The heaven and the heaven of heavens cannot contain (1 Kings 8:27) the one true God who is, from everlasting to everlasting (Psalm 90:2), unchanging (Malachi 3:6).  If he became God then He changed and is not the God of the Bible.  You may worship that god as you please but you cannot claim he is the same God that the Bible presents.  You worship a different God than I.

Comment: @MikeBorden I have not contradicted the Bible at all. If you say I have, then you say that the Bible contradicts itself. That is your position. God says there is no God beside Him, and yet God says He has a Son, the Son of God, who is also our Lord and our God. Look at your own family tree and you will learn with absolute certainty that God is telling the truth. An impotent god is no god at all.
We are the children of God. That is my religion, that is what all Scripture says, no matter how much a man tries to make himself a mere robot, that identity is untruthful. He will regret it.

Comment: @MikeBorden God has changed. He does not change. The Scriptures say so. He is eternal.
The Scriptures say that Emmanuel, that is, "God with us", changed: 
"Jesus grew in wisdom and in stature, and in favor with God and man" (Luke 2:52)
It is true that to us there is no God beside God our Father in exactly the same sense that I have no other father of my body than my earthly father. This is trivially easy to understand once it has been revealed to us by God, when we have received the testimony from His Spirit to our spirit that we are His children, as Paul says in his epistle to the Romans.

Comment: The Father and the Son and the Holy Spirit are one.  No difference in nature, just relationally.  Simple.  Just like the human family you keep referring to.  Which, by the way, you should beware of.  Looking at any part of creation and fashioning God after that image is a wayward path.  God has a created son and a begotten Son.  All in the created son die and all in the begotten Son live.  Full pardon for sins and eternal life in God's presence (which is what is promised) ought to be enough.  Coveting an equal footing with the Lord God Almighty is what brought Lucifer down.

Comment: The god you worship is only one of an uncountable number of gods creating and ruling over uncountable (imaginary) universes.  Man made gods whom Yahweh declares are no gods at all.  If, and I insist upon if, there are multiple universes, realities, dimensions, etc., the God of the Bible has created them all and is, alone, God of them all.  You are contradicted by Isaiah 45:5, whether or not you can perceive or admit it.

Comment: @MikeBorden The universe is very real. God's family is very real. Man did not make the Family of God, the Family of God is self-existent just as God Himself is. But if there is no such thing as Divine begetting then you would deny the central message of Scripture, and Christianity would have little or nothing to offer that other religions don't.
As I said, the reality that I have exactly one earthly father is logically congruent with the spiritual equivalent that we have one God Who is the Father of our spirits.
The notion that God has no family is an unbiblical non sequitur.

Comment: " Know therefore this day, and consider it in thine heart, that the LORD he is God in heaven above, and upon the earth beneath: there is none else." - Deut. 4:39.  "understand that I am he: **before me there was no God formed, neither shall there be after me**. " - Isaiah 43:10b.  "Is there a God beside me? yea, there is no God; I know not any." - Isaiah 44:8b  "For I am God, and there is none else; I am God, and there is none like me." - Isaiah 46:9.  "And this is life eternal, that they might know thee the only true God". - John 17:3.  The assertion of multiple Gods stands in contradiction.

Comment: @MikeBorden This simply reveals the relationship of God to man and is clarified by other Scriptures. God to man is a relationship specifier, just as Father is a relationship specifier. "You have no Father but me, nor shall you ever have any Father but me" is perfectly logically valid and congruent with His statement of Deity towards us. It is true that there is no one like our earthly father. Much more so of God!
Many fathers exist on this Earth and more will exist as such.
We say that God is perfect, He makes His righteous children perfect. He is everlasting, and makes the just everlasting.

Comment: @MikeBorden
"The one who conquers will have this heritage, and I will be his God and he will be my son."
Revelation 21:7
"And you shall be my people, and I will be your God.” Jeremiah 30:22

Comment: "Our word υιος (huios) is the masculine counterpart of the feminine noun θυγατηρ (thugater), meaning daughter, but the opposite of νοθος (nothos), which denotes a bastard or illegitimate child. That means that our word doesn't simply denote one's male biological offspring, but rather a person who has been acknowledged and accepted into a household as someone who has the rank and rights of a male heir".  One need not be transformed into God in order to be a son of God.  We are sons by adoption in Rev. 21, and by the spirit of adoption we cry Abba, Father.

Comment: God has one and only one begotten Son and we are adopted through Jesus.

Comment: @MikeBorden "Someone who has the rank and rights of a male heir" - bingo. Genetics are not even necessary to the equation at this point. "We are the children of God... If children, then heirs". Does nothing to change the potential of man to become perfect even as the Father is perfect, which is the subject you took issue with.

Comment: The word rendered "perfect" has nothing to do with becoming God as the Father is God and everything to do with completeness, as in integrity with no part being at odds with any other part ... just like God is and just like Adam was created to be.  It represents the removal of sin and the reintegration of the whole human person, not deification.

Comment: @MikeBorden Then you acknowledge that the use of the term "perfect" as a means to cope with the doctrine of Theosis and shut it down is inappropriate. In more precise words, one cannot say that God has always been perfect because He is perfect, because man can also become perfect. The special pleading for the allegation that God never changed must come from somewhere else. Also this is contradicted by the meaning of the word "heir".

Comment: Biblically, heirs receive portions rather than the entirety unless there is only one heir.  If there are more than one then the first receives a double portion.  This radically rules out the notion of complete equality in the inheritance.  We are co-heirs with Christ ... not equivalent.

Comment: @MikeBorden The Lord said "All things that the Father hath are mine", yet we can be "joint-heirs with Christ". This is a clear case where "all that the Father has" is not subject to earthly rules of subdivision. For one, the Father continues to live while His children inherit all that He has, and also those who suffer with Christ shall receive will be joint heirs with Him and be like Him.
Joint heirs does not in any way preclude equivalence. So already we have proven that this Living Inheritance surpasses those restrictions of a typical earthly inheritance.